# State parameter value does not match with expected value

Tags: java, grails, oauth, google-oauth, social-authentication

I have a requirement in our project to sign-in user using other providers like facebook,google. For this, i am using social auth plugin. it is working fine with facebook,but with googleplus , i am getting error "State parameter value does not match with expected value", this error comes when user redirect in our app after google, means in getUserProfile().so how can i resolve this.

```
Dependencies are :
runtime "org.brickred:socialauth:4.7"
        compile "org.brickred:socialauth:4.7"
```

my socialauth controller is

```
def authenticate(){
            SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault()
            //You can also pass input stream, properties object or properties file name.
            config.load()
            //Create an instance of SocialAuthManager and set config
            SocialAuthManager manager = new SocialAuthManager()
            manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config)
            // URL of YOUR application which will be called after authentication
            String successUrl = grailsApplication.config.auth.redirect.url
            // get Provider URL to which you should redirect for authentication.
            // id can have values "facebook", "twitter", "yahoo" etc. or the OpenID URL
            String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(params.id, successUrl)
            session.setAttribute("authManager", manager)
            redirect (url:url)
        }

        @Secured('permitAll')
        def getUserProfile(){
            try{
                // get the auth provider manager from session
                SocialAuthManager manager = (SocialAuthManager)session.getAttribute("authManager");
                // Pass request parameter map while calling connect method.
                Map<String, String> paramsMap = SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap(request);
                // call connect method of manager which returns the provider object.
                AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(paramsMap);
                Profile profile = provider.getUserProfile();
                log.debug"user profile"+profile
    //          log.debug"contact"+  provider.getContactList()
            }
            catch(SocialAuthManagerStateException exception){
                log.error("Exception occurs while connecting with SocialAuthManager--->"+exception.getMessage())
            }
        }
```

properties file

```
#googleplus
googleapis.com.consumer_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
googleapis.com.consumer_secret = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: social auth 4.7 have a problem,using social auth 4.6 ,problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem with Version , you can use social auth 4.6 , it works fine